# How do I document roles and responsiblites

Tags: requirements

When working on a requirements document, how do I capture system roles and responsibilities?

E.g. "I'm a manager and I will only use the system to generate reports on xyz".

I was looking for an example online but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may benefit from reading up on Agile Development Methodology. In this methodology requirements gathering is done in the form of "[User Stories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_story)". For example:

"As a manager I want to be able to generate reports on XYZ"

"As a customer I want to be able to see my recent transactions"

etc.

Answer (score 0):

A proper use case should clearly state the Actors involved.

In your case "Manager" is the actor in a "Manager receives daily reports" use case.

Also note that use case Actors just like actors in a theater company may have several roles.

So "Manager" is also an "Employee" and perhaps a "C.C. for CIO".